# Salesforce Screen Flow Dynamically Update Text Field based on Value of Picklist

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I'm trying to display a Text Field in my Screen Flow based on a Picklist Value.
Example: In a Picklist I see all Contracts. Now, when I choose a value from this Picklist I like to display the Account Name in a Text Field. When I choose a new value from this Picklist I like to display the New Account Name.

[image]

Is this possible?